# R what should i do modefify specify col and row by some conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

i create my own function like a but it encounter some problem on runing.

```
# condition and target_col  must be str, 
modify<-function(data,target_col,condition,value){
row_index <- which(eval(parse(text=condition))
data[row_index,target_col]<-value 
return(data)
}
```

i want to implemention this effect

here is my data

```
library(dplyr)

data<-data.frame(c=c("z","x","c","e"),a=c(1,2,3,4),b=(1,2,3,4))

cond_context<-c("z","c")
```

this is i used before , but i think is not effective and elegant, it would alter an entire row

```
result<-data%>%mutate(a=ifelse(c%in%cond_context,1,a))
```

this is use myfunction

```
result<-data%>%modify("a","data$c%in%cond_cotext",1)
```

my function have two problem

```
#first  i can't use %>% smoothly

data%>%mutate(d=1)%>%modify("a","data$d%in%cond_context",1)
this is wrong,  function can't find data$d obj,
i must use like this
data<-data%>%mutate(d=1)
data<-data%>%modify("a","data$d%in%cond_context",1)
# sencond i can't when i use this in a function ,it report cat't find cond_context,i don't know how to solve this proble, but it is ok run step by step on environment.
```

my ideal function is like this：

```
result<-data%>%modify(a,c%in%cond_cotext,1)
```

mybe my describe is too tedious ,so my final question is how to implement my ideal modify function or their is some useful library functcion which i can use directly

thansk a  lot

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: As I read your question, you want to change the element in one column only if the corresponding element in another column has one of a set of values. For example, if an element in column `c` has value "z", then then change the corresponding element in column `a` to 1. Is that right? If so, I think this approach that you mentioned should be effective: `result<-data%>%mutate(a=ifelse(c%in%cond_context,1,a))` (assuming `cond_context` is "z"). It also seems a lot more elegant than the unnecessarily long `eval(parse(...))` approaches.

Comment: i use loop and system.time to compare ,of course my function is much effective ,i made an improvement ,  use eval() directly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(rlang)
library(magrittr)

#' @param data dataframe
#' @param cond_col character. Name of column containing condition is based on. 
#' @param cond vector. Vector containing values to check for in \code{cond_col}. 
#' @param target_col character. Name of column to modify. 
#' @param value vector of length 1. Value to replace with in column \code{target_col}. 
modify <- function(data, cond_col, cond, target_col, value){
  init_factor <- is.factor(data[[target_col]])
  if(init_factor) data[,target_col] <- as.character(data[[target_col]])
  data %<>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!target_col := ifelse(!!ensym(cond_col) %in% cond,
                                         value, 
                                         .data[[target_col]]))
  if(init_factor) data[,target_col] <- as.factor(data[[target_col]])
  data
}
```

As an example, here is code running the function with the output following:

```
test_df <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = "a")
modify(test_df, "x", 1, "y", "b")
  x y
1 1 b
2 2 a
```

As you can see, initially the column `y` had only values of `"a"`. After applying `modify`, it had a value of `"b"` when `x` had a value of `1`, but retained its initial value when `x` was not `1`.

Note that the `#' @param` lines are not part of the function definition. They just indicate what each parameter in the function takes. For example, `#' @param data dataframe` means that the parameter `data` takes input of class `dataframe`.